# Change entire row color if the first characters in a cell is "-"

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to change entire row color if the first character of the cells in column A = "-"

Here is my work, I successfully color the row, but it also colored other rows, which the first character of the cells in column A <> "-"

CEll A1 (-ABS) ///////////////////
CEll A2 (12345-Surface Import)  ----> I don't want this row to be colored

```
Dim Wb3 As Excel.Workbook
Set Wb3 = Application.Workbooks("Test template.xlsm")

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Wb3.Sheets

 Dim SrchRng3 As Range
 Dim c3 As Range, f As String


 Set SrchRng3 = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
 Set c3 = SrchRng3.Find("-*", LookIn:=xlValues)
 If Not c3 Is Nothing Then
 f = c3.Address
 Do
 With ws.Range("C" & c3.Row & ":N" & c3.Row)
 .Font.ColorIndex = 2
 .Interior.ColorIndex = 24
 End With
 Set c3 = SrchRng3.FindNext(c3)
 Loop While c3.Address <> f
 End If


Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I think my main problem is, using the concept of Contain, if that cell contain XXX, then return YYY. But what I need is If a cell's string starts with XXX, then return YYY

Comment: You know you can achieve this using conditional formatting? **Use a formula to determine which cells to format** `=LEFT($A1,1)="-"`

Comment: conditional formatting is not suitable for my situation as my column A is dynamic, which change from time to time. I cannot set a specific range for conditional formatting

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but isn't that what you will also do in VBA, change `Set SrchRng3 = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A65536").End(xlUp))` everytime A changes? Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: @SiddharthRout 

Basically, Column A contains ~ 600 records, from A5 to A605. Now the case is, those records are from externally database, each time I refresh, some might change/add/less.

Here is their format,
CELL A5 = 150311-Surface R
CELL A6 = 250311-Surface E
CELL A7 = 350311-Surface K
CELL A8 = -Surface ABC

My VBA code is looking for those cell in column A with "-*"
So it return all of them to me as they all contains "-Surface"
But all I want is simply "-Surface ABC", which starts with "-", instead of the others, which contains "-"

Comment: It doesn't matter if the data changes. the formula will highlight all the rows where "-" is the **first** character in Col A

Comment: The answer that you have selected below works on the same principle :D `=LEFT($A1,1)="-"`

Comment: Conditional formatting seems to do just fine as per the other comments. If not, you can avoid a loop through worksheet objects/cells through an AutoFilter or Evaluate (to return an array of rows to highlight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because `Find` is going to search for "-" inside the string as well. Not necessarily from the beginning of the string.

see if this helps you, its a simple for loop, that will check if the First letter of the string in column A, is "-" , and then color that full row.

```
Sub color()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long

lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    'check the last cell from A that has value

For i = 2 To lastrow                                'start to loop through column A, from second row if maybe you have a header
    If Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, 1) = "-" Then        'check if first charcater is "-"
       Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.color = RGB(255, 0, 0)   ' if first characther is "-", color entire row
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: you have to add `ELSE` in yout `IF STATEMENT` to remove fil when the row does not start from `-`